# Finding dates for the last full Sat-Fri period in PHP

Tags: php, date

I have a PHP reporting application that needs to fetch data from a third-party API. I'd like to grab a week's worth of data from the last full Saturday-to-Friday period. For example today is Wed 23 Mar, but when I run the report I need data from Sat 12 Mar through Fri 18 Mar. The application accepts the YYYY-MM-DD format for start and end dates. I can't get my head around calculating the dates, particularly if it overlaps months or years.

If anyone can help point me in the right direction I'd be very grateful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$lastFridayTimestamp = strtotime('last friday');
$saturdayBeforeLastFridayTimestamp = strtotime('last saturday', $lastFridayTimestamp);
echo date('Y-m-d', $saturdayBeforeLastFridayTimestamp) . ' ' . date('Y-m-d', $lastFridayTimestamp);
```

Comment: Wow, easy when you know how :) Thanks so much